# React native app rejected on android for background permissions request

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

My app has been rejected by google play for requesting access to the user's background location, but I'm not sure where they are getting that from.

In my manifest I've got this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" /> (< just added this one, still got rejected)
```

The required permissions (apk) listed on google play

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, 
android.permission.INTERNET, 
android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE, 
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT, 
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE, 
com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE, 
com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS, 
com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT, com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE,
 com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS, 
com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE, 
com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS, 
com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, 
com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ, 
com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE, 
com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE, 
com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE, 
me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ, 
me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE
```

I'm using @react-native-community/geolocation to pull the users location, only after they have granted their permissions. So I'm trying to think if there was something that I missed, but the app was accepted two weeks ago.

Anyone dealt with this recently?

Upon further digging i've found that the apk 22074 is listed as active, but I don't seem to be able to delete it or deactivate it. [image].

---

Update #2

So it looks like the three APKs that they mention are in violation are listed in my Closed Testing releases. I have stopped the tracks, but nothing has changed, as I'm still getting emails from google play telling me that the app is asking for background permissions (it's not afaik).

[image]

Comment: Upon closer look at the email they sent, I saw this ```Affected APK(s):
APK:22074``` Which is actually a much older build than the one that I am trying to submit. So somehow they are looking at older versions, rather than the one I am submitting?

Comment: If anyone comes across this and is looking for the answer, it seems that this is the way to handle it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626453/cannot-remove-internal-test-track-build-from-google-play-console