# How to deactivate non-compliant app bundles or APK?

Tags: android, deployment, google-play

From google we have recieved following mail. we tried many times still we are not able to deactivate non compliant bundle/apk.if anybody had faced same challenges kindly help us to resolve this issue.

Pasting content of mail from google.

Please follow the given steps to deactivate non-compliant app bundles or APK

- Sign in to your Play Console, go to App bundle explorer and select
  the track with the policy issue (Internal / Closed / Open testing /
  Production).
- Click "Manage track" and "Create new release"
- If the release with the violating app bundles / APKs are in a draft
  state, discard the release Otherwise, add the policy compliant version of app bundles / APKs.
- **Make sure the non-compliant version is under the Not Included section
  of this release.**
- Enter a release name and click Save. Once saved, click "Review
  release" and then proceed to roll out the release to 100% and
  completely deactivate the non-compliant APK.

If the non-compliant versions are released to multiple tracks, repeat step 2 in each track.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am stucked in the same problem. I don't know if this could help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51426051/9167710

Comment: still got this issue, please help

Comment: I resolved above issue by removing all the apk from every environments. For example from internal, open, closed testing and finally from production too. Kindly again submit apk while following Google's guideline on production.

Comment: @NandaZ able to resolve?